# L2 regularization in tensorflow with high level API

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I know there are some similar questions out there regarding l2 regularization with the layer API from tensorflow but it is still not quite clear to me.

So first I set the `kernel_regularizer` in my `conv2d` layers repeatedly like this:

```py
regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.1)
tf.layers.conv2d(kernel_regularizer=)
```

Then I can collect all the regularization losses with following:

```py
regularization_losses = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
```

And last but not least I have to incorporate the regularization term into the final loss. However, here I am not quite sure what to do, which one of the following is correct?

```py
1) loss = loss + factor * tf.reduce_sum(regularization_losses)

2) loss = loss + tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(regularizer, weights_list=regularization_losses)
```

Or are both of them wrong? The second option seems weird to mean since I have to pass the regularizer as parameter once again, even tho each layer already has a regularizer as argument.

*EDIT*

```py
loss_1 = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=logits, weights=1000)

regularization_loss = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)

loss = tf.add_n([loss_1] + regularization_loss, name='loss')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method is correct. One more way of doing this is via `tf.add_n` function:

```
reg_losses = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
loss = tf.add_n([base_loss] + reg_losses, name="loss")
```

The second method also works, but you'll have to define a *single* regularizer. So it works in your case, but may be inconvenient if you use different regularizers in different layers.

Comment: And let`s say I change my loss from `nn.l2` to `losses.mean_squared_error)` then the loss values have a completely different range, how does the regularizer adapt to this? Or is that my job too?

Comment: Well, I wrote I have to do that `repeatedly` so I have always more than one regularizer. What's the advantage of using `tf.add_n` ?

Comment: When you change the scale of the loss function, it effectively changes the `factor` of your regularization. The best value for `factor` is usually found during hyperparameter optimization.

Comment: Okay, so basically if I change my loss function I also have to change my factor. Many thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: All of the methods are equivalent, I just added one more for completeness. I personally would choose your 1) as it's clear and concise.

Comment: FYI: I get an error when I use: `tf.add_n([base_loss] + reg_losses, name="loss")` --> `TypeError: Using a tf.Tensor as a Python bool is not allowed.`

Comment: I will accept your answer if you fixed the second line as `tf.add_n` does not work for me.

Comment: @thigi hm, it works for me. Can you post your script to a gist, so that I could reproduce it?

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the code of my loss calculation.

Comment: You're using it wrong. Take a closer look at my snippet: note `[base_loss]` instead of `[reg_losses]`. Also in this case `tf.reduce_sum` is unnecessary.

Comment: Ah sorry, that was stupid! updated it. dunno whether it is nicer to use `reduce_sum` or `add_n`

Comment: Would it not be more convenient to output the regularization loss as well? Or do I just want to minimise the loss in the end? so I will only tweak the regularization factor and then see what the total loss is rather than looking at both losses, to see what the impact of the factor actually is.

Comment: The raw value of the loss (base loss or reg loss) usually doesn't tell anything. More important is how it's *changed* during training. So I don't see a reason to output reg loss explicitly.